Why babel.config.js is not created when creating a project on Expo?
Please tell me why when creating a project (npx create-expo-app@latest --template, blank) does not create a file babel.config.js? So in the terminal there are warnings that I could not find (all on the screenshots).[enter image description here](https://i.sstatic.net/Cb32B51r.png)
I tried the -npx expo customize command, but it doesn't generate any of the suggested files at all

Hi, just a side note: using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?.  Thank you

If your project requires a custom Babel configuration, you need to create the babel.config.js file in your project by following the steps below:
Navigate to the root of your project, run the following command inside a terminal:
npx expo customize

This command prompts generating different config files. Select babel.config.js.
ref: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/config/babel/
